# How to post a notification when an observable object has changed

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

trying to post a notification when ever the observable object changes.

this seems wrong. looking for a better way.

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var date: Date {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .modified, object: self) // want to also post notifications for changes, not just publish to owners of the object
        }
    }
    @Published var a: Int {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .modified, object: self)
        }
    }
    @Published var b: Int {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .modified, object: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your intention the solution is to subscribe to default publisher which posts event on any change, i.e.

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var date: Date = Date()  // default values just for demo simplicity
    @Published var a: Int = 0
    @Published var b: Int = 0
    
    private var subscriber: AnyCancellable!
    init() {
        subscriber = self.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] in
            guard let object = self else { return }
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .modified, object: object)
        }
    }
}
```